# Returning variable to UI from asynctask

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-asynctask

I'm trying to return the variable data of type LocationData to my onCreate so that I can add markers to my map.

I get the coordinates in the background and use:

```
 publishProgress(data);
```

I then use:

```
  public   LocationData onProgressUpdate(LocationData data) {


        return data;
   }
```

to pass the location data back to the UI.

I then call the data in the onCreate with:

```
 new EndpointsTask().onProgressUpdate(data);
```

Then I try to add the coordinates to the map with:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(data.getLat(), data.getLongitude()))
         .title("banana"));
```

I do not get any points on the map unless I physically type in lat/long values into where the data.getLat()/data.getLongitude. The lat long values print to the log before the publishProgress so I know I am getting the values correctly.

Why am I not getting the points added to the map?

Complete code:

```
public class FinderActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener  {


GoogleMap mMap;
Location myLocation;
EditText length;
String lengthString;
LocationManager locationmanager;
double lati;
double longi;
String nameFirst1;


   List<Address> address;
   Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_FIRSTNAME = "nameFirst";
private static final String TAG_LASTNAME = "nameLast";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "emailAddress";
private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "streetAddress";
private static final String TAG_STATE = "state";

private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
JSONArray contacts = null;


private static class LocationData {
     private double lat;
     private double longitude;
     private String name;

     public LocationData(double lat, double longitude, String name) {
         this.lat = lat;
         this.longitude = longitude;
         this.name = name;
     }

     public void setLat(double lat) {
         this.lat = lat;
     }

     public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
         this.longitude = longitude;
     }

     public double getLat() {
         return lat;
     }

     public double getLongitude() {
         return longitude;
     }

     public void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name;
        }

     public String getName() {
         return name;

        }

     }
LocationData data = new LocationData(lati, longi, nameFirst1);


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maps);
    mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    if (mMap!= null) {

        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);


        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(17));

        }

    LocationManager locationmanager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria cr = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationmanager.getBestProvider(cr, true);

    Location location = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20, 0, (LocationListener) this);

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng((new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))));


    new EndpointsTask().onProgressUpdate(data);

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(data.getLat(), data.getLongitude()))
         .title("banana"));


}

public class EndpointsTask extends AsyncTask<Context, LocationData, Long> {

    private List<LocationData> locationList = new ArrayList<LocationData>();

    public Long doInBackground(Context... contexts) {

      Contactinfoendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new Contactinfoendpoint.Builder(
          AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
          new JacksonFactory(),
          new HttpRequestInitializer() {
          public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) { }
          });
  Contactinfoendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(
  endpointBuilder).build();

  try {

    String apples = endpoint.listContactInfo().execute().toString();

    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(apples);

    JSONArray jsonArr = jObject.getJSONArray("items");

     for(int i =0 ; i<jsonArr.length() ;i++ ){
         JSONObject jsonObj1 = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);


                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String nameFirst1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_FIRSTNAME);
                    String nameLast1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_LASTNAME);
                    String emailAddress1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                    String streetAddress1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                    String phone1 = jsonObj1.getString(TAG_PHONE);

                    //test to see if made it to string
                    Log.d("YOUR_TAG", "First Name: " + nameFirst1 + " Last Name: " + nameLast1);

                       address = coder.getFromLocationName(streetAddress1,5);

                        Address location1 = address.get(0);

                        // SET LAT LNG VALUES FOR MARKER POINT

                    double lati = location1.getLatitude();
                        double longi = location1.getLongitude();

                         Log.d("Location", "Location:" + lati + " " +  longi);


                         locationList.add(data);
                         publishProgress(data);

     }

    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
      return (long) 0;

    }

    public   LocationData onProgressUpdate(LocationData data) {


        return data;
   }

    }
```

Comment: you will need to start AsyncTask as `new EndpointsTask().execute(FinderActivity.this);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still have not done what I have told you to do multiple times now.

in your `AsyncTask` create a class wide `ArrayList` of `LocationData`

```
ArrayList points = new ArrayList<LocationData>();
```

then in your AsyncTask put every point/data you get when you parse into the list

```
LocationData data = new LocationData()
data.setLatitude(latitude);
//etc.
points.add(data);
```

then in your `onPostExecute` loop the list and plot your points

```
for(LocationData data : points){
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
     .position(new LatLng(data.getLat(), data.getLongitude()))
     .title("banana"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did get it to work your way. But I was thinking I could get it to work by passing the data to the UI through onProgressUpdate. Can it not be done this way?

Comment: the way you want it done no you cant, you would need to create a callback to the main activity. but you are already in the UI then you are in `onPostExecute` so it will make no difference

Comment: have you confirmed that your points are actually valid points?

Comment: It is working great. I uploaded a few addresses to the app engine datastore and they are showing up where they are supposed to. Again, thanks for your help. I'm learning so much from stackoverflow.